# Insert into mysql data

Tags: php

How will I insert into mysql using php if my data comes like this?

```
array(
    [template] => template2
    [quote] => 001
    [date] => 01 December 2016
    [referenceno] => 
    [q_cust_name] => 0
    [q_cat_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => drugs
            [1] => oil
        )

    [p_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Paracetamol
            [1] => liquid nitrogen
        )

    [quot_per_unit] => Array
        (
            [0] => 600/gram
            [1] => 500/liter
        )

    [quot_des] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cures fever. Use only in case of high fever
            [1] => Hazardous Product.
        )

    [quot_price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 150.00
            [1] => 7500.00
        )

    [quot_req_qty] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 10
        )

  )
```

Comment: I have tried using for loop

Comment: Please provide enough information for others to understand your problem. Like table structure (of databse), etc

Comment: Provide us a mapping, What column in PHP array should go to what column in your table...

Answer (score 0):

$x="INSERT INTO `quotation` (`user_id`, `quote`, `date`, `referenceno`, `q_cust_name`, `q_cat_name`, `p_name`, `quot_per_unit`, `quot_req_qty`, `quot_price`, `quot_dis`, `quot_des`, `incident_charge`, `tax`, `quote_total`, `status`)  VALUES";

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_REQUEST['q_cat_name']);$i++)
    {  $x.="('', '".$_REQUEST['quote']."', '".$_REQUEST['date']."', '".$_REQUEST['referenceno']."', '".$_REQUEST['q_cust_name']."', '".$_REQUEST['q_cat_name'][$i]."', '".$_REQUEST['p_name'][$i]."', '".$_REQUEST['quot_per_unit'][$i]."', '".$_REQUEST['quot_req_qty'][$i]."', '".$_REQUEST['quot_price'][$i]."', '".$_REQUEST['discount']."', '".$_REQUEST['quot_des'][$i]."', '".$_REQUEST['incident_charge']."', '".$_REQUEST['tax']."', '".$_REQUEST['quote_total']."', 'draft'),";

    }           
echo $x;
```